# parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated in jwage/purl

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function postIndex(){

$url = new Url('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize');

$url->query->setData([
    'response_type'=>'code',
    'client_id'=> env('DROPBOX_APP_KEY'),
    'redirect_uri'=> env('DROPBOX_REDIRECT_URI')
]);
```

parse_str defined in the purl class takes only one parameter

```
protected function doInitialize()
{
    parse_str($this->query);

    $this->data = get_defined_vars();
}
```

My current php version is 7.1.17.It needs a second 'result' parameter, how should I pass the second required parameter to get rid of this error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not something as simple as `parse_str($this->query, $result); $this->data = $result;` ?

Comment: _“parse_str defined in the purl class takes only one parameter”_ - you are confusing the function definition with a simple function call here - what you have here in `doInitialize` is the latter.

Comment: the simple task seemed so overwhelming. Thanks, @CD001

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), `parse_str` didn't start raising a deprecation warning until 7.2, but in any case, it makes sense to move over to the two-argument usage.

That code sample is thankfully very straightforward, and can easily be updated as follows:

```
protected function doInitialize()
{
    parse_str($this->query, $this->data);
}
```

The `jwage/purl` library already [had basically this exact fix applied](https://github.com/jwage/purl/commit/a1584ea255b063b455029023a8bae9b35eebabe3#diff-609d10d6f6a95be06e214b1d25b4a376), but it doesn't look like it's been re-tagged since then so if you pulled it in via Composer you'll need to manually [require the master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916183/how-do-i-get-composer-to-download-the-latest-commit-in-the-master-branch-from-gi).